# Using instruments to find memory leaks

Tags: ios, memory-leaks, automatic-ref-counting, instruments

I've tried to read almost every decent tutorial in the internet, but still can't understand what is really happening here:[image]

I've "Hide System Libraries" and "Invert the call tree", but I do not understand how to find actual code responsible for for example this leak. Any tips are appreciated. May be I am missing something obvious. I am getting hundreds  of leaks, however I am using `weak` in closures, I do not have classes referencing each other etc. But it looks like I am missing something fundamental.

Comment: I am also facing same problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem shown in your screenshot is Instruments can't find your app's debug symbols. Instruments is showing memory addresses instead of function names. You are not going to be able to find the source of your memory leaks in Instruments without function names, even if you invert the call tree and hide system libraries.

Make sure your project is generating debug symbols. Check that the Generate Debug Symbols build setting is set to Yes. If your project is generating debug symbols, Instruments may be unable to find the dSYM file that contains the debug symbols. In Instruments choose Instrument > Call Tree > Locate dSYM. The dSYM is usually in the same directory as the release version's application bundle. The following article has additional information:

[Instruments: Locating dSYM Files](http://meandmark.com/blog/2016/02/instruments-locating-dsym-files/)

Comment: Ok, I've done everything, but stacked on importing with "The UUID of  /appname/ does not match the UUID for libdyld.dylib", not much information in google, any tips?

Comment: I've made it! Thanks a lot! That what I was missing

Answer (score 3):

Memory leaks can be difficult to track down. This is likely going to be a time consuming process, so be prepared. In the end, there is usually a lot of trial and error with debugging memory leaks. The "Memory Leaks" instrument has actually only detected one leak for me in the past. I've always had to track them down myself using the "Allocations" instrument.

One of the things that has helped me in the past is to start by trying to figure out what objects are actually being leaked. Click on the allocations instrument (the row above "Leak Checks"). Now try sorting by number of objects released or amount of memory used. See if there are any objects that have a count of 0 released when they shouldn't be sticking around. See if there is an object type that is taking an abnormal amount of memory.

Memory leaks are always due to developer mistakes with memory management. There are some minor memory leaks that exist in some of the lower level private APIs in Foundation and UIKit. At those lower levels, they are dealing with a lot more manual memory management, so its much easier to make tiny mistakes. You can't really do anything about those, but they are relatively rare.

If your application is working just fine, you may not need to worry about fixing these. There is some cost benefit analysis you want to do here. If this isn't impacting performance or stability, is the time investment in fixing these right now worth the minor benefits it will provide you and your users?

However it is worth nothing that memory leaks can add up, so if a user has your app open for a long time, the amount of leaked memory will eventually become a problem if you continue to leak more objects over time. At some point the application will crash and the user will have to re-open. But if your memory leaks are small enough that this doesn't become an issue unless the app has been open for HOURS, is it really that much of a problem anyways? That's always a judgment call on your part.

Comment: here comes my second question: why do they happen? my app is not lagging etc, it works fine, but still I am getting those leaks from not even my classes, but some libraries, `UIViews` and I can't imagine what else. I do understand `ClassA` <-> `ClassB` and `[weak self]` in closures kind of leaks, but what else?

Comment: but, sorry I did not notice, I am using Swift and ARC, what's more all my `UIViewControllers` are `deinit()`, so here is my actual problem: what is left in memory if `UIViewController` is released? Shouldn't all in it be released and if not - should not it be in memory?

Comment: Any objects can be leaked. Even if the object that created or retained them  is deallocated. For example, if two objects create a retain cycle, the object that had the initial retain on both of them can be released, but they will never be. Additionally, any lower level code that uses manual reference counting could be forgetting to release an object.

Comment: thanks a lot, short and complete answer is much better then all those guides)